# NodeJS: Readstream.read() not working with Buffer.concat()

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, filestream

I am trying to read **chunks** from a **ReadStream** using the following code creating **BlobContent** of a specified **thresholdSize** and then passing that to a function **putBlock()**:

```js
let blobContent = Buffer.from([])
let contentLength = 0
const thresholdSize = 100 * 1024

readStream.on('readable', function () {
  let chunk
  while (null !== (chunk = readStream.read())) {
    Buffer.concat([blobContent, chunk], blobContent.length + chunk.length)
    contentLength = contentLength + chunk.length
    if (contentLength >= thresholdSize) {
      putBlock(blobContent, contentLength)
      contentLength = 0
      blobContent = Buffer.from([])
    }
  }
})
```

I am not getting **BlobContent** as expected for this code.
Can someone check what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Buffer.concat` returns a new Buffer which is the result of concatenating all the Buffer instances in the list together.

So try `blobContent = Buffer.concat([blobContent, chunk])`.